# Repeated Header when using Datagrid as a Field Children of Datagrid?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, react-admin

The header of Datagrid is repeated every other-row?
I want a header (like excel) just once at the top.

How can I fix it?
How can I customize or build a new Component similar to Datagrid?

```
      <Datagrid>
           <NumberField
                source="ManagementFee"
                label="Phí quản lý "/> 
            <NumberField
                source="tax"
                label="Thuế "/>
            <NumberField
                source="max"
                label=" tối đa"
                textAlign="center"
            />
            <DateField source="createdDate" label="Ngày tạo" />
            <DateField source="modifiedDate" label="Ngày sửa" />
            <ArrayField source="portfolio" label="Danh mục" >
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="symbol" label="Mã " />
                    <NumberField
                        source="initialRate"
                        label="Tỷ lệ  ban đầu"
                       />
                    <NumberField
                        source="maintenanceRate"
                        label="Tỷ lệ duy trì"
                        />

                    <NumberField
                        source="rate"
                        label="Tỉ lệ "
                    />
                    <NumberField
                        source="bankRate"
                        label="Tỉ lệ kho"
                      />
                </Datagrid> 
            </ArrayField>

            <EditButton />
        </Datagrid>
```

Comment: A screen shot of the problem happening in the header would help. Some typos and gramma were fixed in this edit.

Answer (score 3):

`<Datagrid>` renders as a table with an initial row for headers. If you use `<Datagrid>` as one of the fields of another `<Datagrid>`, you'll be nesting tables one with the other. Not only is this not supported by react-admin, I strongly advise against using it from a UX point of view.

Put your `<ArrayField>` in an `expand` component to reveal that information only on row click, or write a custom field component to display the array field data in another way.